# Connect to remote desktop (VNC) in as few steps as possible

Tags: finder, remote-desktop

Connecting to the desktop of a remote mac is very tedious:

1. Open Finder.
2. "Go" > "Connect to Server..."
3. vnc://username@IPaddress (From the second time on, this URL is already in the box)
4. Press "Connect" .
5. Type password.
6. The remote lock screen shows up.
7. Type password to unlock.

My remote Mac doesn't show up in the "Network" section of the local Finder (probably because it's on a totally different network. I use VPN). The "remember password" feature doesn't work when connecting, maybe because a security measure is installed (malware detector using AI).

So, basically I'm looking for a scripting solution.